# Get Items from a Listbox in WPF and write in other List

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Ive created a Listbox in Wpf with a Itemtemplate and Datatemplate:

```
<ListBox Name="LBox" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="2" SelectionMode="Single">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="LTxtBox" Text="{Binding NAME}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        <ProgressBar x:Name="PBarLbox" Grid.Column="1" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding FORTSCHRITT}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I can add/change/Remove Items in my listbox.

Now ive tried to save the Items in a txt file.
If i Add a item, its work well, i can save them in my txt File.

Now ive tried to save changes in my Listbox, but how can i get access to my Items in a Listbox? .

Here is the Code behind for my Observable List and Property Class.

```
private ObservableCollection<TodoItem> Todo =new ObservableCollection<TodoItem>();
    public class TodoItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string NAME { get; set; }
        public int FORTSCHRITT{ get; set; }
         //###########################################
        public string Name
        {
            get { return this.NAME; }
            set
            {
                if (this.NAME != value)
                {
                    this.NAME = value;
                    this.NotifyPropertyChanged("NAME");
                }
            }
        }
        public int fortschritt
        {
            get { return this.FORTSCHRITT; }
            set
            {
                if (this.FORTSCHRITT != value)
                {
                    this.FORTSCHRITT = value;
                    this.NotifyPropertyChanged("FORTSCHRITT");
                }
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
```

My thought was, if im gonna to close my Window, Override the old List with the new Changed Items in my Listbox.

For this ive Created a Window close Event:

```
void DataWindow_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {  // TODO
       // Wenn er das Fenster schließt soll er alle Daten die im ToDo Fenster sind speichern und die alte Datei Überschreiben.
       
    }
```

Ive tried with For each to get access, ive tried for loops but i cant get access.

With:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
            string[] arr;
            foreach (var x in LBox.Items) 
            {
                list.Add(x.ToString());
            }
            arr= list.ToArray();
            string display=String.Join(Environment.NewLine, arr);
            MessageBox.Show(display);
```

I can see That he got access to the items but he print the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1lBo.png)

How can i print the right values ?

Comment: I dont really see your problem, you are getting your items successfully. Are you maybe looking for how to override `ToString()` so that it doesn't print the type? `toDoWpf.MainWindow+TodoItem` ? - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring

Comment: How does your ObservableCollection relate to the ListBox? It is a usual to bind the ListBox.ItemsSource to a collection. That way you just Save/Load the collection, and don't need to touch the ListBox.

Comment: Any reasoning behind the double members `NAME`/`Name` or `FORTSCHRITT`/`fortschritt`? Seems wrong.

Comment: Why don't you enumerate the Todo collection instead? You don't need to access the control. Now that you have access to each individual TodoItem, you can construct the string by referencing the properties. or override the TodoItem.ToString to return a useful string representation.

Comment: Also replace the array and list  with a StringBuilder if you need to construct strings in multiple steps.

Comment: And replace the public backing properties with private fields. See [Using Properties (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties) to learn how to define properties properly.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not access the control to get the data items. Rather access the source collection directly:

**MainViewModel.cs**

```cs
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ObservableCollection<TodoItem> TodoItems { get; }

  public MainViewModel()
  {
    this TodoItems = new ObservableCollection<TodoItem>();
  }

  public async Task SaveDataAsync()
  {
    var fileContentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (TodoItem todoItem in TodoItems)
    {
      fileContentBuilder.AppendLine($"{todoItem.Name}, {todoItem.Fortschritt}");
    }

    await using var destinationFileStream = File.Open("Destination_File_Path", FileMode.Create);
    await using var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(destinationFileStream);
    string fileContent = fileContentBuilder.ToString();
    await streamWriter.WriteAsync(fileContent);
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  private MainViewModel MainVieModel { get; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitilaizeComponent();

    this.MainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
    this.DataContext = this.MainViewModel;
    this.Closing += SaveDataToFile_OnClosing;
  }

  private async void SaveDataToFile_OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    => await this.MainViewModel.SaveDataAsync();
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <ListBox itemsSource="{Binding TodoItems}">
    ...
  </ListBox>
</Window>
```

Properties in C# must look like this (pay attention to the proper casing: use camelCase for fields and PascalCase for all other members). Also use `nameof` to specify the property's name:

```cs
private int fortschritt;
public int FortSchritt
{
  get => this.fortschritt; 
  set
  {
    if (value != this.fortschritt)  
    {
      this.fortschritt = value;
      this.NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(this.Fortschritt));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the Stringbuilder part saved my life :D 
As you can see im clearly a newbie, can you recommend me some books ?

Comment: Sorry, not really. I gues C# in a Nutshell or C# in Depth. Haven't read any of them. I highly recommend to consult Microsoft Docs and the .NET API browser regularly. For example [Naming Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines#in-this-section), [Patterns - WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern)

Comment: or [Data binding overview (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0). The examples in the API browser/reference are also very good. For example [INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=netcore-3.1#examples). Reading the remarks will give you some good understanding.

Comment: The last example shows you how to improve your INotifyPropertyChanged implementation. Many things to learn by just browsing through the API reference.+